# Fading in and out particles

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas, conditional-statements

## Explanation of Experiment

I'm trying to make a basic particle emitter in JavaScript with canvas. I have the basics down, but one thing I can't figure out is how to smoothly fade in the particles after creation, and fade out the particles before deletion.

Here's a basic version of my `Particle` object on creation:

```
{
    alpha: 0,
    color: "blue",
    velocityX: .5,
    velocityY: .5,
    gravity: .01,
    currentLife: 1000
    startLife: 1000
}
```

You can view the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/8g5csscf/

The numbers are generally random, but relatively near those values.

Each animation frame, the object is updated and the particle is rendered as a circle on the screen by its `color` and `alpha` value. Its `currentLife` is decremented by one, per animation frame. Once its `currentLife` is zero, a new object takes its place.

## Question and Problem

How can I fade in the object after its conception, and fade it out before its deletion?

I'm assuming I might need to use FPS or time changed (delta t), with if statements based on half of the `startLife`, but I'm just not sure how.

## Important Note

Yes, I know I can update the alpha. The problem is getting it to fade in/fade out by a certain value that adds up to 100 by its half life.

Comment: it's unclear what you want. css or js solution? Where's your code? You only posted an object with some data in it. Just change it's alpha from 0.0 to 1.0 and you got the effect

Comment: @Gavriel I'll be updating my question in about a minute. Yes, I know I can update the alpha. The problem is getting it to fade in/fade out by a certain value that adds up to 100 by its half life.

Comment: Why half life? If a particle is created, then you might fade it in, but that's just a visual way to show it to the user. You can chose that it's fading in 1 sec. Then the particle can live 60 seconds, then disappear and for a visual effect you fade it out for 1 sec. I don't see why in this case you would want the fade-in for 30sec, fade-out for 30sec

Comment: @Gavriel That's a good point, and thanks for being attentive. I'll show you some code in a second.

Comment: @Gavriel Updated accordingly with a new non-collaborative JSFiddle. The code there is what I've been able to come up with, that fades out near the end of its life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, then I would put something like this (pseudocode) into the update function:

```
if (currentLife > startLife/2 && currentLife > startLife-100) {
    alpha++;
} else if (currentLife < startLife/2 && currentLife < 100) {
    alpha--;
}
```

If you want it to fade-in for half-life, then:

```
if (currentLife > startLife/2) {
    alpha=200*(startLife-currentLife)/startLife;
} else if (currentLife < startLife/2) {
    alpha=200*(startLife-(startLife-currentLife))/startLife;
}
```

And draw each particle with the alpha value it holds.

To fix the filckering change the last 2 lines of the constructor of Particle to:

```
this.alpha = 0;
this.rgbaColor = hexToRgba(this.hexColor, this.alpha);
```

Comment: Thanks, the half life function works really well. Although there's an odd flicker when I implement it, it's nice.

Comment: I've updated the JSFiddle to include the latter conditionals, but again there's still that flicker. Let me know if you can figure it out.